# Remove "selected" attribute from a select box in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 dropdown boxes and one contains options like 'staff and company'
if i select staff another dd comes with staff name otherwise it will be disabled and selected with empty value...
my problem is after a search with staff in first dd and name in second dd works fine, then i select company with first dd and empty with second still the search affect with staff name what we did previously.

One thing staff list loaded in second dd(not like ajax), i am trying change the disable/enable through jquery

what i tried is below

```
if($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").val()!="1"){
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");

    $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").attr("disabled", true);

}
$("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").change(function() { 
        if($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").val()=="1"){
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        else{
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");                
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").attr("disabled", true);
            }
 });​
```

please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but the `selected` attribute on `<option>` is only there to inform the browser which one it should pre-select when it loads the page — changing it with JS won't change its current value that will be submitted with the form, you need to use `val("")` on the `<select>` instead.

Also, disabled elements don't get submitted with the form, so .NET on the server is probably using the value from the previous postback if it is saving it with ViewState, so it's better to hide the second drop-down rather than disable it:

```
if($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").val()!="1"){
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").hide();
}
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").change(function() {
    if($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy").val()=="1"){
        $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").val("");
        $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").hide();
    }
});​
```

Also, took the liberty of tidying up a bit:

```
var ddlEnteredBy = $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlEnteredBy");
var ddlStaffList = $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList");

ddlEnteredBy.on("change", function() {
    if (ddlEnteredBy.val() == 1) {
        ddlStaffList.show();
    }
    else {
        ddlStaffList.val("").hide();
    }
}).change();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't help me it still using the previous value

Comment: $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList option").attr("selected", "");
                     $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlStaffList").val('');​ this is working but if try to disable it will not work, i don't know what happened after disable

Comment: Ah, of course, when a form element is `disabled` the value does not get submitted with form, so then your .NET code server-side will still be using the selection from the previous postback. About to update my answer...